# Excel checkbox change row background color

Tags: excel, vba

i create some table, and make a datestamp when i enter data

in column "A" the date is shown in column "E" , so i know when data is entered.

I put checkbox in column "F", but I need help with next:

1. When checkbox is checked the date must be written in column "G"
2. The background from "A to D" (but only in this row) must be changed to red color
3. The data from A, B and C must be copied to another sheet also in A,B and C

I hope someone will help me because i stuck :(

I also attack a screenshot.

Thanks in advance

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the tour and read through [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and post a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck.

Comment: Can you confirm, are you using ActiveX checkbox control or excel user control ?

Comment: I use form control checkbox, but i can add activeX check box...

Answer (score 0):

The procedures will help you get the macro operational, ensure you try the code on a copy of your workbook

Add a command button (ActiveX control) and paste the macro
Note: You need to ensure that you place the Command Button in the worksheet where you have your check boxes.

Step 1: 
Copy the “LoopCkBoxesAddDateStampClrCelsCopy()” macro

```
Sub LoopCkBoxesAddDateStampClrCelsCopy()
Dim lRow As Long
Dim CkBx As OLEObject

'For/Next loop cycles through all checkboxes in worksheet
For Each CkBx In ActiveSheet.OLEObjects
    lRow = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    'If the checkbox is checked then accomplish the lines of code between the If/End If
    'The part after the "And" ensures that if a date is in the cell it will not be over written
    If CkBx.Object.Value = True And CkBx.TopLeftCell.Offset(, 1).Value = "" Then
        'Next line of code puts the date in first cell to left of the checkbox
        CkBx.TopLeftCell.Offset(, 1).Value = Format(Date, "mm-dd-yyyy")
        'Next line of code colors the first 4 cells in checkboxs' row
        CkBx.TopLeftCell.Offset(, -5).Resize(, 4).Interior.Color = vbRed
        'Next line of code copies the first 3 cell in the checkbox row to the first empty row on sheet 2
        Sheet2.Cells(lRow, 1).Offset(1).Resize(, 3).Value2 = CkBx.TopLeftCell.Offset(, -5).Resize(, 3).Value2
    End If
Next CkBx 'loops to the next checkbox

End Sub
```

Note: If you plan on pasting your cells to a different worksheet, please change both Sheet2s in the code.

Step 2: 
On the Developer tab, in the Controls group, click Insert, and then under ActiveX Controls, click the Command Button.

Step 3: 
Click the worksheet location where you want the command button to appear.

Step 4:
Right click the button, click View Code. This will launch the Visual Basic Editor.

Step 5:
In the VBE, highlight the Private Sub CommandButton1_Click() and the End Sub, and Paste the macro

Step 6:
Close the Visual Basic Editor, and click Design Mode Button image to ensure design mode is off.

Step 7:
Select the checkboxes in your worksheet and click the button to run the macro

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for answer. I do it all like you write, but it only work after i enter data and than go to code and press run. If i add data after that it will not work. The date is written but cells are not colored copied to sheet 2.

Comment: With out seeing what you have and how you are implementing it I can't help. You must use ActiveX check boxes. The button is selected after you have update your worksheet. This code was tested on the mock data(based on your example picture) and worked perfectly.

Comment: Here is file, google docs cant see check boxes but when you download you can see full file.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1XWm6LbZcjsKH4dIfbx3H2LD_1_VDClHd